# Angular Slider Issue

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, slider

I'm currently developing an image slider component in Angular, but I'm encountering an issue where the slider isn't displaying as expected. I've provided the code for my slider component below.

**slider.component.html:**

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="container-slider">
    <div *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'slide': true, 'active-anim': currentSlideIndex === i}">
      <img [src]="getImageUrl(i)" alt="">
    </div>
    <button class="btn-slide prev" (click)="prevSlide()">
      <img src="../../../../assets/icons/prev.svg" alt="Previous">
    </button>
    <button class="btn-slide next" (click)="nextSlide()">
      <img src="../../../../assets/icons/next.svg " alt="Next">
    </button>
    <div class="container-dots">
      <div *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index" class="dot" [ngClass]="{'active': currentSlideIndex === i}" (click)="currentSlideIndex = i"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**slider.component.css:**

```
.container-slider {
  max-width: 650px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 36px;
  margin-left: 85px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .container-slider {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .container-slider {
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 95%;
    float: none;
    max-width: none;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out 0.4s;
}
.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.active-anim {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-slide {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.287);
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-slide img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.prev {
  top: 50%;
  left: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-60%);
}

.next {
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-60%);
}

.container-dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
}
.dot {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
.dot.active {
  background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
}
```

**slider.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})
export class SliderComponent {
  @Input() images: string[];
  currentSlideIndex = 0;

  nextSlide() {
    this.currentSlideIndex = (this.currentSlideIndex + 1) % this.images.length;
  }

  prevSlide() {
    this.currentSlideIndex = (this.currentSlideIndex - 1 + this.images.length) % this.images.length;
  }

  getImageUrl(index: number): string {
    return this.images[index];
  }
}
```

**This is how I use my slider:**

```
<app-slider [images]="['../assets/images/img1.jpg', '../assets/images/img2.jpg', '../assets/images/img3.jpg']"></app-slider>
```

**This is how my slider currently looks:**
[image]

**This is how slider should look:**
[image]

And I've noticed that the layout and appearance of the slider are not matching my expectations. Specifically, I want the slider to have a fixed width of 650px, a height of 500px, and be centered horizontally on the page. However, despite applying these styles, the slider is not displaying as intended.

Could someone please review my code and provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: ATENTION: use `src="assets/icons/next.svg"` or `src="./assets/icons/next.svg"`. Angular copy your assets folder in the same folder where you have the index.html and the bundles files (the .js). NOT depend the folder structure of your aplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `:host` to make the slider always full width and flexbox, so that the child is centered using `align-items: center;justify-content: center;` after that, we need to set the dimensions on the first element of the component `.slider` to `flex` and set it to grow to the contents.

After using the below styles, it seems to work!

```
.container-slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 36px;
  margin-left: 85px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 650px;
  height: 500px;
}

:host {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gpd5mn?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fapp%2Fslider%2Fslider.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fslider%2Fslider.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fslider%2Fslider.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fslider%2Fslider.component.spec.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Thanks, but after your changes my slider just disappeared.

Comment: @dkobzar please replicate your scenario in the stackblitz and share back!

Comment: Never mind, your code works, I just had `display: flex;` in the `div` where the slider is located, I removed `display: flex;` and everything works